# Null не появляется в schema.rb после миграции

Tags: ruby-on-rails, миграция

Есть вот такая миграция

```
class AddApplicationToNotificationEvent < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :notification_events, :application, :string, :null => true
  end
end
```

Но после неё в `schema.rb` нет `:null => true`

```
create_table "notification_events", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "subject_id"
    t.string   "subject_type"
    t.integer  "eventable_id"
    t.string   "eventable_type"
    t.string   "service"
    t.string   "kind"
    t.text     "data"
    t.datetime "created_at",                        :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                        :null => false
    t.boolean  "read",           :default => false, :null => false
    t.string   "application"
  end
```

А в БД есть. Почему?

Comment: судя по указанию `:null => false`, `:null => true` подразумевается по умолчанию

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вообще говоря, ответ на этот вопрос — **потому что разработчики Rails так решили**.

*Почему они так решили?* Можно спросить у них, конечно.

Но скорее всего, потому что **SQL работает так же** (а точнее, DDL баз данных, его поддерживающих), так работают современные РСУБД, под давлением известных стандартов. Без явного указания они считают, что колонка любого типа может не иметь значения, а обратное указывается явно с помощью `NOT NULL`. Так и здесь.

Answer (score 1):

По умолчанию null разрешен. По этому в схеме этот параметр не отображается. Вот если он не разрешен, то вот тут это учитывается [код обработки null](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/7f2037a990fd81e07f612169f72e8d59fc2a4e52/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_creation.rb#L80)